# hmac HTTP API request

Tags: objective-c, api, http, hmac

I am trying to create a iOS app that connects to the api server of a forum. The connection itself works fine, the headers are correct, but my code on how I create a hmac and how I set the signature is incorrect.

Code of the signature string:

```
NSString *signature = [[[self getHMACSHA256ForData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li%@", requestId, contentDigest] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] keyValue:KEY]  base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];
```

Code of the getHMACSHA256ForData method:

```
- (NSData *)getHMACSHA256ForData:(NSData *)data keyValue:(NSString *)keyValue
{
    CCHmacContext ctx;
    const char *key = [keyValue UTF8String];
    const char *str = [data bytes];
    unsigned char mac[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmacInit(&ctx, kCCHmacAlgSHA256, key, strlen(key));
    CCHmacUpdate(&ctx, str, [data length]);
    CCHmacFinal(&ctx, mac);

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:mac length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}
```

I am trying to do it as the same as the PHP client of the API: https://gist.github.com/sevvlor/3419c34adb3ee93e42729208cfa33ef7

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Again, break your whole code into multiple lines/code. It's too hard to debug or read. `NSString *dataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li%@", requestId, contentDigest]; NSString *dataToEncode = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSData *hmacSignatureData = [self getHMACSHA256ForData:dataToEncode keyValue:KEY]; NSString *hmacSignatureStr = [hmacSignatureData  base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn]; NSString *cleanHMACSignature = [hmacSignatureStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];` And try to debug each line.

Comment: Now, do you have a sample input/output for those who can't test the PHP API code? What's your current output value (even if wrong) with the input? Alsow, why "withCarriageReturn" if you remove them afterwards?

Comment: The API doesn't use HMAC anymore, it seems.